# Ubuntu freezes immediately after login despite seemingly successful install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, freeze

It seems that I've successfully installed Ubuntu, but it immediately freezes after I log in to my user account. I'm not sure why this is the case. I've attempted to use boot-repair from a live USB, but for some reason the live OS freezes while boot-repair is running. Here is the boot info created by boot-repair: [http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qN4VRXWmn2](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qN4VRXWmn2/). I think this may have something to do with the fact that my computer runs UEFI.

EDIT: This is actually the second time I've tried installing Ubuntu. The first time I think I used UNetBootIn to install Ubuntu as a directory on my C drive. This didn't work either and had the exact same problem as my current installation.

Also, here's some more information about my system: I have a Dell Inspiron 5577 laptop.

Comment: What is your system spec?

Comment: Did the system previously run Ubuntu?  I've seen this behaviour on systems that have the wrong memory speed installed or are overclocked in some way.

Comment: @George Udosen I edited the post to answer your question. What other info do you need? I'd assumed pastebin had most of the system info.

Comment: I've got similar issue on my laptop `DREAM MACHINES Clevo G1050-15`, installing Ubuntu 18.04.