# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes immediately after login. But it was successfully installed

Tags: boot, uefi, 18.04

First of all - this question could be similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1033798/568682) and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/1034366/568682) in general (reason), but has different details.

I've bought laptop `DREAM MACHINES Clevo G1050-15 (G1050-15UA22)` and installed on it Ubuntu 18.04, but it freezes after login.

I think the general issue is in finishing installation. Every time (I have installed Ubuntu on this laptop a lot of times during last 2 days) it freezes after pressing **`Restart Now`**.

### I tried some cases to resolve this issue:

1. Installing Ubuntu in UEFI mode.

   `efi 500MB
   swap 16000MB
   ext4 / *all left space*`
2. Installing Ubuntu in `Legacy` boot mode.

   `ext4 /boot 500MB
   swap 16000MB
   ext4 / 150000MB
   ext4 /home *all left space*`

The both of this cases have the same `reboot` issue.

### Good is:

- I can use recovery mode to completely load OS.

I tried to dig dipper and found information how to manage boot steps. I can set as default booting booting in recovery mode (it is very inconvenient comparing with usual booting, but it is definitely better than pressing `Esc` to get a chance to catch booting menu).

Right now I'm trying some soft for manage booting and customizing rules\scripts. I dislike this way, but I do not have better idea.

Let me know please if I must use another approach, thanks.

### P.S.

Also I tried approaches like:

- suggestion for Ubuntu 14

  `sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
  sudo apt-get install unity
  sudo shutdown -r now`
- using boot repair tool advises (it doesn't help me with prepared solutions to resolve default problems. My linux knowledge are too pure to customize it)

  `$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
  $ sudo apt-get update
  $ sudo apt-get install boot-repair
  $ boot-repair`

...it would be very useful for me to help you with details in order you ask something with suggested scripts or clear algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original answer is on [superuser forum](https://superuser.com/a/1083166/617285). The next command resolved my issue.

```
systemctl reboot --firmware-setup
```

Comment: What to do in the UEFI setup?